# Adding and reading a custom section in AppSettings in C#

Tags: c#, appsettings

I hope you can help me.

I'm supposed to add a new type of values to an AppSettings file (already existing with some values). Those values are a whole list of special folders so I thought the best way would be to have a new section for those folder values so that the file would look like this:for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="usPath" value="folderName1" />
        <add key="tcPath" value="folderName2" />
        <add key="usGUID" value="folderID1" />
        <add key="tcGUID" value="folderID2" />
    </appSettings>
    <updateFolders>
         <add key="folderID3" value="folderName3">
         <add key="folderID4" value="folderName4">
    </updateFolders>
</configuration>
```

Reading and writing within the already existing appSettings-tag is no problem but I haven't find a way yet to modify the updateFolders section. I'm really new to using AppSettings in this way so I don't know too much about what's possible and what's not. In addition to that I think the AppSettings file might have been set up in a wrong way from the very beginning (it gets created by using a System.IO.File-Writer).

Answer (score 0):

see ConfigurationManager.GetSection
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection(v=vs.110).aspx